# How optical media type is identified by the burner?

Tags: media, optical-drive, dvd-burning, optical-media

How CD-DVD Burning apps & the drive are able to identify the media type in the drive i.e. whether the inserted disk is CD-ROM or DVD-R or DVD-RW and so on?

I understand that the session info is written on the disk, however does information about media type pre-encoded on the media somewhere say in Lead-In area or so in some way?

I have searched the net but this specific info does not seem to be clearly available.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have Gathered the Drive **Lazer**/Program on the PC what the PITCH value is on the disc. Explained in this [Article](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Comparison_CD_DVD_HDDVD_BD.svg).

The Image is below showing the Different Pitch values for each.

[image]

Comment: Thank for this input @NetworkKingPin. Seems the link to the 'Article' as mentioned above points back to the inserted Image. In case there's a separate article apart from this image, could you please update the link?

Comment: Fixed the link.